# How do I make my navbar / header change from user login

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Currently I am developing a website that will allow users to: trade, sell, and buy with each other. I am using PHP and Bootstrap for the CSS and I have the navigation created. I also have the registration page created however when they log into their profile I would like their header to change.

I know this might be a stupid question, but how would I change the header to replace links once the user has logged on? I assume I would have to inquire JavaScript?

Index.php

```
<?php 

       $pageTitle = "Vomica";
       $section = "home";

?>

<?php include 'INC/header.php' ?>


       <div class="container-fluid">



       </div>

<?php include 'INC/footer.php' ?>
```

header.php

```
<html lang="EN">

    <head>

        <title> <?php echo $pageTitle; ?> </title>

        <!--Universal Encoding for HTML5-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <!--Making it mobile friendly-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!--Bootstrap's CDN-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet" href="CSS/custom.css" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <!--Header-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"> Vomica </a>

                </div>

                <div>

                    <!--Left-->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li class="<?php if($section == "home") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="index.php"> Home </a> </li>
                        <li class="<?php if($section == "buy") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="buy.php"> Buy </a> </li>
                        <li class="<?php if($section == "sell") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="sell.php"> Sell </a> </li>

                    </ul>

                     <!--Menu Items on the Right-->
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="<?php if($section == "signing") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="signup.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span> Sign Up </a> </li>
                        <li class="<?php if($section == "logs") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="login.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> </span> Login </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> </span> Logout </a> </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

                </form>

            </div>

        </nav>
```

Comment: *... I will leave it out if it's un needed.* We Need Your Code.

Comment: I don't know why index.php code won't go into the text box.

Comment: *"I assume I would have to inquire JavaScript?"* - No, use serverside sessions.

Comment: Im so confused on how to do this and no one will help. This site is just negative.

Comment: I fixed the formatting for your `index.php` but for future reference see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for guidelines on formatting your code. Also, at time of this comment, your question only has 13 views - at least 3 of which (you, Nana, Nana's upvoter) were prior to your request for help on formatting - that hardly equates to the site being negative. Simply noone had yet noticed or understood what you meant. Patience mate, we'll try and help in due time. :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the following logic.

1 - Check if the user is null or not, if it is null: Your Logged out navbar ?>

2 - If user is not null, Your Logged In navbar ?>

Comment: Like with what language would I change That up with?

Comment: PHP + HTML. PHP to Print up the HTML navbar.